# How to add command line arguments to PyCharm's "mypy (Official)" plugin?

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy

I seem to be using PEP 484 and PEP 526 type annotations more and more in my code.

I mostly use vim+syntastic, but I'm exploring my options a little, specifically I'm looking into how I'd like using PyCharm for some projects.

PyCharm has two mypy plugins.  For now at least, I've gone with the one called "Mypy (Official)".

Is there a way of configuring PyCharm to use "mypy --disallow-untyped-calls --ignore-missing-imports file1.py file2.py" ?

My intention is to make PyCharm more strict in its type checking (--disallow-untyped-calls), while at the same time not generating errors about dependencies that don't include type annotations (--ignore-missing-imports).

I know I could write a shell wrapper to do this, but I'd rather go through the PyCharm GUI this time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you navigate to `Configure plugin...` for the `MyPy (Official)` plugin in PyCharm (right click on the "MyPy Terminal" pane), you can customize the command used to run `mypy`. On my machine (MacOS) with a clean install of the `MyPy (Official)` plugin, the default is:

```
dmypy run -- --follow-imports=error .
```

If you change this to

```
dmypy run -- --follow-imports=error --disallow-untyped-calls --ignore-missing-imports .
```

then the options you requested should be enabled.

Note that `--follow-imports` must be set to `skip` or `error` when using the plugin.